# Get property of nested object

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to get all the property of an object and their value.
my code here give me all the value for the "simple" properties of my object :

```
                    foreach (var prop in dataItem.Value.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        if (prop.Name == "CurrentSample")
                        {
                           //Doesn't work
                           var internProperties = prop.GetType().GetProperties();
                           foreach (var internProperty in internProperties)
                           {
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("internProperty.Name + " : " + internProperty.GetValue(prop, null));
                           }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(prop.Name + " : "+ prop.GetValue(dataItem.Value, null));
                        }
                    }
```

My problem is on my "CurrentSample" property, it contains 2 property of it's own (a TimeStamp and a String).
I can't find a way to retrieve those informations.

I've tried to apply the same principle, but I don't get the right information at all.
I CAN access those value by using a simple dataItem.Value.CurrentSample.Value or dataItem.Value.CurrentSample.TimeStamp but would like to know a more proper way to make it work.

For now instead of printing my TimeStamp and Value with their value I get a big list of properties, I suppose all the properties of the class property :

```
ReflectedType : MTConnectSharp.DataItem
MetadataToken : 385876007
Module : MTCSharp.dll
PropertyType : MTConnectSharp.DataItemSample
Attributes : None
CanRead : True
CanWrite : False
GetMethod : MTConnectSharp.DataItemSample get_CurrentSample()
SetMethod : 
IsSpecialName : False
CustomAttributes : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData]
```

Comment: Are these properties protected/private ?

Comment: No, they are all public.

Comment: Ok, then what is the error ? You said it doesn't work, but why ?

Comment: instead of printing an expected TimeStamp : $myTimeStamp and Value : $myValue it print me a huge list of property, I suppose all the properties of the class property ...
I edited my question to make more clear what I get at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have an issue with this line:

```
var internProperties = prop.GetType().GetProperties();
```

It should return the PropertyInfo properties, since you don't get the property value first.

With:

```
var internProperties = prop.GetValue(dataItem.Value, null).GetType().GetProperties();
```

It should work better.

And for this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("internProperty.Name + " : " + internProperty.GetValue(prop, null));
```

You still want the prop value, not the property itself.

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
internProperty.GetValue(prop, null)
```

Means you're trying to get the value of a property of `prop`, which is a `PropertyInfo` instance. Instead you should use:

```
if (prop.Name == "CurrentSample")
{
    object currentSample = prop.GetValue(dataItem.Value, null);
    var internProperties = prop.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var internProperty in internProperties)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("internProperty.Name + " : " + internProperty.GetValue(currentSample , null));
    }
}
```

PS. Personally I try to avoid using `var` in any reflection code - it's already hard enough to read.